# How to pass a class/module definition into another file

Tags: python, import, module, conventions

I'm a beginner in OOP Python and I just wanna know this:

This is **file.py**:

```
class Card():

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        """Initialization method"""
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def get_rank(self):
        """Function get_rank returns a rank (value) of the card"""
        return self.rank
```

When I wanna create and pass an object to the function "get_rank" in this file, I can do this:

```
card1 = Card(10,"Diamond")
card1.get_rank()
```

But how can I create and pass an object in another file? There is another file called **test_file.py**, it's a testing file (py.test). So **file.py** is for code only, **test_file.py** represents parameters (variables and objects) which are passed to **file.py**. In **test_file.py** is also variable "expected_result" with a correct result. Then when I use "py.test" (bash), it shows me, if the result is correct or not.

I understand this non-OOP example:
**abs.py**:

`def split_text(text):
    - code -`

**test_abs.py**:

```
def test():
    text = 'abcdefgh'
```

Please help, thanks for any advice :)

Comment: In Python, unnecessary accessors are frowned upon.  These are a Java idiom—there's just no need for a function like `get_rank`.  Use `card1.rank`, and make it a property if you ever require a non-trivial accessor function.

Comment: [Python standard convention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978557/association-between-naming-classes-and-naming-their-files-in-python-convention) recommends: since your file defines *Card* class (and/or Deck, Hand and so on), call it *card.py*. Never call it file.py, like @HaiVu says.

Comment: I'll keep in mind not to use "file.py" anymore. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `test_file.py`:

```
from file import Card

...
card1 = Card(10, "Diamond")
# Do something with it
```

By the way, do not name your file file.py: `file` is a built-in function.

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks :) I'll keep in mind not to use "file.py" anymore.