# python import nested class

Tags: python, import, nested

I'm new to python. This is not my actual case, it's just my curiosity about importing nested class.

So I have a **main.py** and **test.py**.

**test.py**:

```
class one():
   class two():
      def twodef():
         pass
```

so in my **main.py**, I can do `'import test'` or `'from test import one'`. But I got error when do: `'from test.one import two`'.

```
error : ImportError: No module named one
```

Anyone can explain this?

Answer (score 3):

You can only do `from module import name` for names that exist in the module's global scope - basically, names that are defined in top-level module code.  Names that are defined in lower-level scopes - for example within classes as in your example - are not importable.  You need to import the object that contains the name, and access it from there.

```
from test import one
my_two = one.two()
```

Answer (score 0):

**inside test.py**

```
class One:
    class Two:
        @staticmethod
        def twodef():
          print("twodef")
```

**My main logic:**

```
from test import One
two_obj = One.Two
two_obj.twodef()
```

Remove the parenthesis at the end of class definition.

**Coding standards:**

Always declare your class names in upper camel case (class one => class One).

[For more about scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765677/python-nested-classes-scope)

**Preference:**

And if you have a single class inside python file, always name that file in that class name but in lower camel case. (test.py => one.py). I have thought this as a standard earlier, but seems its practiced widely. I would use this because, if then project size grew and if you end up having a lot of classes and modules, it's logical and easy to access, rather than visiting the module to find the class name.
[Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711884/python-naming-conventions-for-modules)
 [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978557/association-between-naming-classes-and-naming-their-files-in-python-convention)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
from test import one

two_object = one.two()
two_object.twodef()
```