# Python import class from another class

Tags: python, python-import, python-class

**This is an example to better understand my problem:**

fileno1.py

```
class MyClass:
    class MySecondClass:
         value = {"some": "dictionary"}
```

**What I tried:**
fileno2.py

```
from fileno1.MyClass import MysecondClass
print(MySecondClass.value)
```

but that gave me: 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fileno1.MyClass'; "fileno1" is not a package`

**Now my question:**
Is it somehow possible to import `MySecondClass` to another file in the same directory so that the variable `value` is accessible there?

Comment: Where are the files located?

Comment: that's now how imports work, you can only import top level defined objects, not nested ones

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python import nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36514851/python-import-nested-class)

Comment: @12944qwerty they are located in the same directory

Comment: @gold_cy Yes, but is that the only way how you can do it? Because in my original Project, I have more and deeper nested classes that need to be accessed.

Comment: Why do you even have the need to nest class definitions?

Comment: @Matthias I am building an app automation framework with uiautomator2 and with nested classes it is easier to keep track of where the elements are located in the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the correct syntax is to import the top-level class, then call the nested class through the top level class.

```
from fileno1 import MyClass

print(MyClass.MySecondClass.value)
```

There's a guide on nested classes [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/inner-classes-python) that you might find useful.